# How to Dynamically add points to line in Kineticsjs?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas, kineticjs

I want to add points to line dynamically. The `setPoints(Array)` will only take a new set of array of points but I want to extend that line by adding another point to it.Also I have use a transition while adding point to line. How to do it ?

This is not working

```
line.transitionTo({points:[x,y],duration:1,easing:'ease-out'});
```

Comment: there is no way right now with the transition object. It is slated for a future release.

Answer (score 0):

You currently cant do transitions, but here is what you can do:

```
var points = line.getPoints();
points.push(x); // new x point 
points.push(y); // new y point
line.setPoints(points);
layer.draw();
```